# Communicating with blackberry from website

Tags: java, html, blackberry

I would like to make a way to communicate with my blackberry to call a vibrate alert and a led alert through my website. What would be the best way of doing this? Would it be [using java or html5](http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/)? Can you just give me the fundamentals. I am not looking for any detail.

Answer (score 0):

In this sort of situation, where there is only one BlackBerry involved, I would suggest you just integrate some email send functionality into your web site, and send your BB an email.

I'm not an html expert, but if you were doing this in Java, you would either register for a push Service:

[BlackBerry Push](https://developer.blackberry.com/services/push/)

or write some polling service that ran in your BlackBerry and checked a web page you had set up.

Both of these options I think are significantly more work than sending an email.

Comment: Thank you! I am actually abroad and using a sim that isn't blackberries and building a chat app online for it. so I want every new message to vibrate! would you reccomend blackberry push?

Comment: Push is definitely the correct option, but I think it requires you have BlackBerry Data plan on your BB7 device (not so for BB10 I believe).  But there are cross platform chat applications already available for the BB.  Are you sure you are not just "recreating the wheel"?